# Netflix Conductor Health Check

Tags: netflix-conductor

What is the way to setup health check on netflix conductor? There is an endpoint for health check, but it always returns healthy even if the dynomite has some issues.

```
/api/health
```

returns

```
{"healthy":true}
```

If dynomite or elastic search is down then conductor health check should return false. How do I get this working?

Update: As of 11/8/2023 -  This issue is addressed by the contributors.

Comment: hit an endpoint that will need elasticSearch to be up, a search endpoint.
hit an endpoint that will need to look up database.
Or simply setup healthcheck for those services, separately. Don't couple them up.

Comment: I have a simple python flask application created that aggregates and computes the status of elastic, dynomite and conductor, then responds with the status which is integrated with monitoring framework.

Comment: "If dynomite or elastic search is down then conductor health check should return false"

You actually answered your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was addressed by the contributors in 2023